# OpenGL Sine function move towards point

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have a Open GL project where I have a 2D object that is supposed to move towards a destination point until it hits it, then it will stop until the currentX and Y have reached the Destination X and Y. Here's my code in my glutTimerFunc:

```
void callbackTimerGlutFunc(int value)
{
    spinX += SPEED_X;
    spinZ += SPEED_Z;
    if (spinX > 360.0) {
        spinX = spinX - 360.0;
    }
    if (spinZ > 360.0) {
        spinZ = spinZ - 360.0;
    }

    if (xPos != DESTINATION_X || yPos != DESTINATION_Y)
    {
        if (xPos < DESTINATION_X)
            xPos += speed;
        if (xPos > DESTINATION_X)
            xPos -= speed;

        yPos = cosf(xPos); // THIS IS THE NEW Y CALCULATION
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(100, callbackTimerGlutFunc, value);
}
```

Basically, I increment the current x (xPos) based on wether it's farther or closer away to the Destination X. Pretty obviously this doesn't work. I'm positive I'm just using cosf wrong. Anyone know how I can get a nice sort of "sine wave" to my destination x and y?

OH, I'm using this function in my display function:

```
glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, 0.0);
```

Comment: Still working this issue?

Answer (score 0):

cosf takes in a double (floating point) that is input as Radians.  This means that with a 1.0 increment there will only be ~4 steps in each direction of y.  You might try incrementing x by some floating point value such as 0.1 or something.